# what is my xmr mining capacity

Tags: mining-hardware

processor:2 duo cpu T6570@ 2.10GHz
RAM: 3GB
operating system: 32 bit
Windows 7 pro

what would be my expected daily return using my hp laptop with these specs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-bitcoin-will-i-mine-right-now-with-hardware-x)

Answer (score 3):

You can try mining with `monero-wallet-cli` to see your hashrate but I'm pretty sure it will be below 30H/s (a laptop i3 CPU). With this, you'd be getting about 0.006xmr/day. You can estimate mining profits [here](https://moneroworld.com/), just scroll down a bit and type in your hashrate.